# one sided derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives

Show that if $ f'(a^+) $ and $f'_+(a) $ exist, then $ f'(a+) = f'_+(a) $.

Here $ f'(a+)  = \lim_{x \to a^+} f'(x) $ and $ f'_+(a) = \lim_{x \to a^+ } \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} $

$\textbf{Attempt:}$ What I've tried doing is using the definition of a limit. So $\forall \epsilon > 0, \exists \delta_1, \delta_2 > 0 $ such that for any $ x \in (a, a + min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}) \implies |f'(x) - f'(a+)| < \epsilon $ and $ |\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a} - f'_+(a)| < \epsilon $. Then from this,

$ |f'(a^+)| - \epsilon < |f'(x)| < |f'(a^+)| + \epsilon $

$|f'_+(a)| - \epsilon < |\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x-a}| < |f'_+(a)| + \epsilon $

Here I am stuck. I would like to somehow show that $ |f'_+(a) - f'(a^+)| < \epsilon $, and my idea was to try and show $ |f'(a^+)| + |f'_+(a)| < \epsilon $, but I'm not sure if that is possible given what I have, and if I am approaching the problem in the right way.

Comment: I don't think you can bound $|f'(a+)| + |f'_+(a)|$ because that quantity can be arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 1):

Use the mean value theorem to get that there is some $c \in (a, x)$ such that
$$
\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} = f'(c).
$$
Now we can take the right sided limit of both sides. Since $c$ is trapped in $(a, x)$, so $c \to a^+$ as $x \to a^+$. So $f'(c) \to f'(a^+)$ as $x \to a$. So we get
$$
\lim_{x \to a^+} \frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} = \lim_{x \to a^+}f'(c) = f'(a^+).
$$
So $f'(a^+) = f_+'(a)$.